# Show Image from database in a Blazor grid

Tags: database, image, datagrid, blazor

I'm having problems showing/displaying an Sql Image in a datagrid.
The code I use is:

```
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var e in @EntitiesResult.Entities)
    {
        <tr class="col-sm">
            <td class="text-sm-center">
                <img src="@(@e.Image != null ? (() => GetImage(e.Image)) : "img/no-camera-sign.jpg")" alt="" width="75">
            </td>
            <td class="text-sm-left">@e.IsahPrimKey</td>
            <td class="text-sm-left">@e.ExtraInfo</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@e.IsahTableName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

So there is a table column showing images. The idea is if there isn't any image in the database stored on a specific row than a default image is shown (no_camera_sign.jpg). But if  e.image is not null than a GetImage function is called. This function is called:

```
        protected string GetImage(byte[]? image)
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            return $"data:image/png;base64, {Convert.ToBase64String(image)}";
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this function is never fired and I don't understand. If the Image is null than the dummy image is shown. So that works but the GetImage function is never fired.
Can someone please explain how to do this...

Comment: If GetImage() is never fired then it follows that e.Image is null.  Adding some break points to the code might be the best way to determine the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code is just wrong

`<img src="@(@e.Image != null ? (() => GetImage(e.Image)) : "img/no-camera-sign.jpg")" alt="" width="75">`

You are saying: if e.Image is not null return a lambda that - if something invoked it, would return an image... but there is nothing to call it, and it is probably just getting ToStringed.

Try just calling the GetImage method

`<img src="@(e.Image != null ? GetImage(e.Image) : "img/no-camera-sign.jpg")" alt="" width="75">`